# AngularJS and DataTables refreshing data

Tags: angularjs, datatables

My project outputs results to a DataTable from an AngularJS controller function, but I'm running into some strangeness when I try to modify my search params. The first rendering of the table works as expected. But when I select different options and run the search again, extra rows appear in the table, but the info section shows the previous search's row count, and changing the number of rows shown via the length menu causes the new rows to disappear. Here's my table declaration, using attributes to wire up DataTables:

```
<table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOptions" id="search-results" class="display nowrap datatable cell-borders" style="width: 100%;">
```

And this is my AngularJS controller code:

```html
$scope.dataTableOptions = {
        dom: "lfBrtip",
        lengthMenu: [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],
        language: {
            emptyTable: 'No items matched your search criteria'
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Export',
                className: 'button button:hover',
                extend: 'csv'
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.getItemInfo = function (model) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $scope.getUrl('/My/ServerSide/Url'),
            data: { model: $scope.model }
        }).then(function successCallBack(response) {
            
            $scope.model.SearchResults = response.data;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            
            alert("There was an error gathering the entity information. Please try again");
        });
    };
```

I'm not sure why submitting new queries with different params doesn't simply update the data in the DataTables table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't ```data: { model: $scope.model }``` be ```data: { model: model }``` which is the parameter you are passing in?

Comment: You can also simplify your $http call: ```$http.post($scope.getUrl('/My/ServerSide/Url'), { model: $scope.model}).then(...)```

Comment: Can you verify the results are you getting back from your API is correct by using Fiddler or Postman?

Comment: The model is getting passed to the server-side controller with the properties set as expected. I appear to be getting valid results back, and am not getting any errors as my DataTables table is rendered. The extra rows as I change search params are appearing in the table. However, at the bottom of DataTables where the info section details how many rows there are, it shows the original search's row count, and if I change the length menu, the extra rows disappear. No idea why. I even modified the $http call to a GET, and passed each search param by itself, rather than part of a model. No change.

Comment: Esaith - You're correct, but they map to the same object, so my mistake didn't cause any problems in that regard.

Comment: I might be easily missing it, but how does the $scope.model.SearchResults get mapped to the data table? I see the $scope.dataTableOptions, but I dont see within that object nor the html to where it the data is being set.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a bit of an ugly hack to get this to work. Even DataTables author wasn't sure how to get around the issue of using AngularJS with DataTables, so I had to force a reinitialization every time the form posted. I persisted the search params to localStorage, and called location.reload(). Then when the page loads and the AngularJS init() function runs, I pick up the search params and call the search function from inside an Angular document ready function, like this:

```
$scope.init = function () {

    $scope.ValidationErrors = [];

    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.SearchResults = [];

    $scope.model.ItemNumber = localStorage.getItem("itemNumber");
    $scope.model.StartDate = localStorage.getItem("startDate");
    $scope.model.EndDate = localStorage.getItem("endDate");

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        if ($scope.model.ItemNumber) {
            $scope.getItemRecords();
        }
    });

    localStorage.clear();
};
```

And then of course I clear the localStorage after the query. Not terribly elegant, but it'll have to do for now.